# Django form translation

Tags: python, django, internationalization, translation

How to translate form labels in Django? I'm trying to use ugettext_lazy, but there's no effect. All site content is translating the right way, but forms are not.

User should have ability to change language manually, so I wrote LocaleMiddleware:

```
class LocaleMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        if (request.user.is_authenticated):
            try:
                translation.activate(request.user.data.language)
                request.LANGUAGE_CODE = request.user.data.language
            except:
                translation.activate(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)

        response = self.get_response(request)
        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.
        translation.deactivate()
        return response
```

But forms are still in default language.

Form example:

```
class DiscussionCreateForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"name": "title", "id": "title", "class": "form-control"}), label=_("title").title())
    first_message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"name": "first_message", "id": "message", "class": "form-control"}), label=_("message").title())
```

Middleware list:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'PortalCore.middleware.LocaleMiddleware.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'PortalCore.middleware.OnlineMiddleware.OnlineMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: are you using the default LocaleMiddleware? did you put your middleware before or after that?

Comment: No, i don't. Added my middleware list into the first post.

Answer (score 1):

why you are using .`title()` in label.? you should use `title()` for dynamic string not static string.

you can define label with capitalize string because you are doing Capital first character of title string. So define directly in label. if you have string in variable then title() is usable.

```
label=_('Title')
```

same also in message string